# Why set DAY_OF_WEEK for repeating alarm don't change date if today's Sunday?

Tags: java, android, date, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

I'm using alarmmanager in android for set a repeating alarm for days selected by the user, that's works fine but if actual day is Sunday that's don't work correct. Let's see. If today's Sunday(7) and I set the alarm for Monday (8) and Tuesday(9) when I see the calendar toString() the date configured is 7, don't change, but if today is other day it's works fine only happens when today's Sunday.

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,h)
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,m)
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.MONDAY)//repeating for Monday if today is Sunday 8, and I set MONDAY, the new date most be Monday 9
Log.d("test",calendar.toString())
```

What's happening?

Comment: If this is for Android, you should say so.

Comment: What is your actual problem in this case? Does the alarm not fire? Does it throw an exception? ...?

Comment: @MonsterDruide1 the problem is that the alarm not fire because if today's is Sunday don't change the date for Monday

Comment: But... you're explicitly setting the `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` to monday, right? Why should the current weekday influence the outcome then?

Comment: Yes. But, if current day is Sunday don't set it the day of week to Monday..do you understand me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### java.time through desugaring

Consider using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work.

```
    LocalTime alarmTime = LocalTime.of(23, 45);
    ZonedDateTime alarmDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Africa/Porto-Novo"))
            .with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY))
            .with(alarmTime);
    
    System.out.println("Alarm date and time: " + alarmDateTime);
```

Output when running just now (Monday, February 8):

> Alarm date and time: 2021-02-15T23:45+01:00[Africa/Porto-Novo]

If you wanted the alarm to happen already today, use `nextOrSame()` instead of `next()`.

### What went wrong in your code?

While it’s quite common for programmers to run into one of the many confusing points about the `Calendar` class, you have run into *two*  of them:

1. `calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.MONDAY)` may set the date of the `Calendar` object either to the previous or to the next Monday. Which one it picks does not only depend of the day of week but also of the settings of the `Calendar` object, which will typically be different on different devices.
2. When next you call `calendar.toString()`, the string you get will not reflect the necessary changes to the `Calendar` object after changing the day of week. I would immediately expect that the day of week has changed, but the old value of day of month will still be printed. I am not going to study the documentation well enough to give you a precise answer. The `Calendar` does not compute its fields until you call `get()` or some other designated method that causes the recomputation to take place.

There are plenty of reasons for not using `Calendar`.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.